# How to create a PKCS12 file with intermediate certificates?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, pkcs#12, jks

I successfully managed to create a PKCS12 file with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in foo.crt -inkey bar.key -out out.p12
```

However SSLChecker (https://decoder.link/sslchecker) shows that the chain doesn't contain any intermediate certificates. I got an ca-bundle file from my SSL provider. Is there anyway to convert this file to the PKCS12 format?

I need this for a ssl secured spring boot server. So maybe a JKS file would work aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A jks would work as well but you should use the standardized pkcs12 format. However you should have your .crt file in pem format and add the intermediate and root cert to it before creating the pkcs12 file with openssl. See https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm Use your received intermediate and root cert of course.

Comment: @Chr3is Thanks, it worked. If you want, you can post this as an answer.